# Uniform continuity: not understanding a paragraph from Protter's book

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have a doubt about uniform continuous function. I am following the book Basic Elements of Real Analysis by Protter. He mentioned following thing with a diagram:
[image]

But, I was unable to see, why the author is "fixing $\varepsilon$" and saying smallness of "$\delta$" for the failure of uniform continuity of the function in the diagram. I could not understand his paragraph

*A function may be continuous on a set $S$ without being uniformly continuous. As Figure $3.7$ [graph of function like $1/x$ on positive real line] shows, once an $\varepsilon$ is given, the value of $\delta$ required in the definition of ordinary continuity varies according to the location of $x_1$ and $x_2$; the "steeper" the function, the smaller the value of $\delta$ required.*

Can one clarify this paragraph?

Comment: The def of [Uniform continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity#Definition_for_functions_on_metric_spaces) says that **for every** $\epsilon$ there is a $\delta$, irrespective of the point $x$ where we "measure" the continuity. In the example above, this is not so: if we change "location" along the diagram of the function, we need different values of $\delta$.

Comment: IMHO uniform continuity cannot be "seen" using plots, it is a concept really non-visible. The reason is that it is a "global effect", so to be seen you need so check something in the whole plot, so the shape of a curve is not very informative, but in the case you see that the curve have infinite slope at some point